# Replace WinRM with OpenSSH on Windows for use with Ansible on AWS

Tags: windows, ssh, amazon-web-services, ansible, packer

Currently when running extended builds (`Packer`/`Ansible` based) on Windows we have found that WinRM has errors so frequently as to be unusable and have had to fall back to running some large build jobs manually as a result. Using a host in AWS as the source of the builds (rather than remote) has helped somewhat, eliminating connectivity as one of the error causes, but the number of failures is excessive and costly, since the builds then restart from scratch even if they have been running for hours.

The [Ansible documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html#windows-ssh-setup) mentions that `OpenSSH` can be used (at your own risk since it is experimental) for configuring Windows hosts in lieu of `WinRM`. However, there is little guidance given in terms of how to set this up.

In addition to a suspicion that `ssh` might be more reliable than `WinRM` as a connection method for Ansible, using `ssh` on port 22 would simplify some of our security rules and bring Windows into line with our Linux build hosts from a connectivity perspective. The ideal would be to create a re-usable build job to allow us to create a base `AMI` (from the official Windows Server 2019 `AMI`) to act as a new base for our Packer/Ansible jobs. Having never used `OpenSSH` on Windows, nor attempted to use `ssh` to connect to Windows with Ansible, if anyone could share a working config or at least pointers that would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requires several steps, and you will generally want to update it every so often to get a more recent version of Windows.

Here is a [repository on Github](https://github.com/comerford/windows-ssh-base-ami) which will (in eu-west-1 by default) take the latest official Windows Server 2019 image and install OpenSSH, configure the server, copy keys such that the Administrator user is accessible over `ssh`, and finally create an AMI which will have `ssh` available on boot. This build will use `WinRM` to do the initial work, but once created `ssh` can be used instead.

Also included is an example of how to use that new base image in an Ansible run (to install some build tools) when connecting via `ssh` rather than `WinRM`.

Comment: Thanks for that repo. That was useful. I still can't ssh in with Ansible, but at least I was able to check a few more things.

Comment: I'm still using this approach for several pipelines and I use SSH to get into the Windows instances based on this image consistently, including with ansible without issues, but I even recently just spun up a base AMI for testing manually and was able to SSH into it -  so it's definitely possible

Comment: I figured it out.  It was my Antivirus quickly killing any powershell script.  Specifically Bitdefender.  It wasn't easy to figure out as there are no useful error messages.  I just got lucky by noticing an pop-up dialog at some point.